# Origin of the REST API pattern: PUT takes what GET returns

Tags: api, rest, design-patterns

We use a pattern where a client (e.g. Angular) can get a set of resource representations (aka entities) using `GET /things` and return any one of those entities as the payload to `PUT /things/{id}`.

All well and good (as long as the id is in the uri and not in the payload) unless the GET response entities include summary information that makes no sense in a PUT.

Be that as it may, I'm looking for the origin or proponents of this GET-out, PUT-in pattern (with or without modification for reality) in order to clearly show that it is not part of the REST specification. I have found cases where purely idiomatic choices such as this have been beatified as being "RESTful", and exceptions -- by extension -- heretical. I think this process is called pseudepigrapha.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no REST specification, it is an architectural concept, hence the implementations will vary.  In fact, you will frequently see POST being used for creating and updating.

Answer (score 0):

RESTful does not tell you things at an operation level. In fact, contrary to popular perception, HTTP is not officially a de-facto REST communication protocol but it has become so because of its wide adoption as protocol of choice on WWW(World Wide Web). So, the question of getting something through GET and then sending it back as a PUT is not a spec. Rather its something which might be evolving as a practice and cannot be advocated as a design principle/spec.

REST is an architecture. REST or Representational State Transfer deals with representations of your entity's state transferred over the network. In practical implementations - entities are the business objects, representations are in JSON formats and states are composed out of the values carried in each JSON message over a network protocol.

Coming back to your question, as HTTP itself is not dictated by REST, the design for first doing HTTP-GET and then HTTP-PUT is not a specification. It can,at best, be quoted as a best practice.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it is not REST. My question is:

What is it called and who thought it up?